# Oracle Database external table issue. ORA-29913, ORA-29400, and KUP-04004

Tags: database, oracle, nosql, oracle-sqldeveloper, external-tables

**EDIT: I solved some classpath issues and now I get the following error in the log file that's generated when performing "SELECT *"**

> UP-04004: error reading file /home/oracle/tweet-dataloc/nosql.dat
>
> KUP-04017: Operating system message: Error 0
>
> KUP-04017: operating system message: /home/oracle/processor/nosql_stream: line 4: java: No such file or directory

**Note that that file is EXACTLY in that path, and has 777 permissions. End of edit**

I am making an external table pointing to an Oracle NoSQL database where the data is stored as key-value pairs.

**NOTE that for this example, I am placing every directory in /tmp which all users at OS level can access, so we take away any OS permission related problems**

First, I create the two virtual directories in SQL developer, grant permissions to my user (nosqluser) and of course, create the external table:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY ext_tab AS '/tmp/tweet-dataloc';
CREATE DIRECTORY nosql_bin_dir AS '/tmp/processor';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY ext_tab TO nosqluser;
GRANT READ, EXECUTE ON DIRECTORY nosql_bin_dir TO nosqluser;
```

And then, I create the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "NOSQLUSER"."TWEETS3" 


("CREATED_AT" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "ID_STR" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "TEXT" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "LOCATION" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "VERIFIED" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "FOLLOWERS_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "FRIENDS_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "LISTED_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "FAVOURITES_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "STATUSES_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "CREATED_AT_USER" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "COUNTRY_CODE" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "FULL_NAME_PLACE" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "NAME_PLACE" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "PLACE_TYPE" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "IS_QUOTE_STATUS" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "QUOTE_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "REPLY_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "FAVORITE_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "RETWEET_COUNT" NUMBER, 
    "FAVORITED" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "RETWEETED" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "FILTER_LEVEL" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "LANG" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "TIMESTAMP_MS" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL( 
      TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY "EXT_TAB2"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS( 
          records delimited by newline
          preprocessor nosql_bin_dir2:'nosql_stream'
          fields terminated by '|' 
          missing field values are null 
          reject rows with all null fields 
      )
      LOCATION ('nosql.dat')
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;
```

Finally, I show you how my nosql_stream script and nosql.dat files look like:
**/tmp/processor/nosql_stream:**

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/latest/bin
export CLASSPATH=/home/oracle/processor/*
java oracle.kv.exttab.Preproc $*
```

**/tmp/tweet-dataloc/nosql.dat:**

```
<config version="1">
  <component name="publish" type="params" validate="true">
    <property name="oracle.kv.exttab.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:/@//relacional:1521/ORCLPDB1.localdomain" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="oracle.kv.exttab.connection.user" value="nosqluser" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="oracle.kv.exttab.tableName" value="nosqluser.tweets2" type="STRING"/>
  </component>
  <component name="nosql_stream" type="params" validate="true">
    <property name="oracle.kv.exttab.externalTableFileNumber" value="0" type="INT"/>
    <property name="oracle.kv.exttab.totalExternalTableFiles" value="1" type="INT"/>
    <property name="oracle.kv.formatterClass" value="formatter.TweetFormatter" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="oracle.kv.hosts" value="bequi_kvlite_1:5000" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="oracle.kv.kvstore" value="kvstore" type="STRING"/>
  </component>
</config>
```

This last file is generated through a Publish function performed on the NoSQL Database end. You can follow the process [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/nosql/external-tables/cookbook.html).

Now, **the problem** is even though the records are processed like you can see here:

> Fri May 10 08:16:34 +0000 2019|1126762942307811331|RT @annknownityy: Future doctor, lawyer, engineer, med tech, nurse, cpa, psychologist, diplomat, biologist, teacher, architect, in the offi?|Sycamore Girl?|Caloocan City, National Capita|false|85|190|0|7804|3131|Sat Mar 21 00:09:46 +0000 2015||||||false|0|0|0|0|false|false|low|en|1557476194346
>
> Fri May 10 08:16:34 +0000 2019|1126762943347953664|University of
>   Ibadan (UI) School Fees Schedule for 2018/2019 Academic Session ?
>   http somelink  ? Learn
>   More|OlusegunFapohunda|Earth|false|592|5|3|104|6851|Thu Feb 11
>   21:49:57 +0000
>   2010||||||false|0|0|0|0|false|false|low|en|1557476194594
>
> Fri May 10 08:16:34 +0000 2019|1126762943498948609|RT @zinadabo1: Pls
>   we need help, I was just informed that Rotimi Akeredolu increased Ondo
>   state university tuition from 35k to150k.

The data is not accessible. When I do a "SELECT * FROM nosqluser.tweets3" what I get is:

> RA-29913: error executing call from ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH
>
> ORA-29400: error in data cartdrige
>
> KUP-04004: error reading the file /tmp/tweet-dataloc/nosql.dat

Since the registers are shown, I know that the NoSQL database is accessible, and the data is Formatted and read correctly. In fact, up to here the process should be complete, so why can't I access my data?

Comment: Is there any further information in the external table's logs?

Comment: The log is too big for me to comment, but a good version is:
<CREATED AT - CHAR(255) 
Ended in '|' 
Trim white space just like SQL loader> this is repeated for every column parameter (name, rt_count, etc). Then, last information is: KUP-04004: error while reading the file /home/oracle/tweet-dataloc/nosql.dat
KUP-04017: Operative System message: Error 0
KUP-04017: Operative System message: /home/oracle/processor/nosql_stream: line 4: java: command not found

Comment: I also must mention that **the 12c and the NoSQL DBs are both in docker containers** within the same network, of course. However, the SQL Developer is Windows Native. I can connect to both DBs though, so I didn't mention it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nosql_stream file must look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java oracle.kv.exttab.Preproc $*
```

In other words, you have to specify to the nosql_stream where Java is, even when it is already specified in the environment variables or the .bashrc file.

This explains why it works on the container where the 12c is deployed since it is a "native" Linux system and makes us of these variables; meanwhile through the local SQL Developer these can't be accessed properly, and thus the file couldn't be properly executed.